# Fixing the Role Instance Id in Azure Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-emulator

I have a couple of cloud services, in my local system whenever I run them using Azure Emulator, the Role Name and the Role instance. Is there any way how I can fix them, i.e., every time I debug the application in my local system the role name and instance id remains the same?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the problem you're facing and what's the ideal output you're expecting? It is not clear from the post.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://en.blog.gbellmann.technology/2015/07/27/assigning-a-custom-name-to-cloud-services-instances/ but, as @GauravMantri says, it's not clear from your post.